# Convert call from spawn to fork-exec in C

Tags: linux, qnx

I have code which looks like this in Linux:

```
return_code= spawnp(cmd, 3, fd_map, NULL, argv, environ);
```

I need to convert this from QNX to Linux - so I need to use fork-exec since spawn is not available in Linux.
1) How can that be done ? Is this right ?

```
pid = fork();
if (pid ==0) /* child */
    exec(cmd, argv, environ);
```

2) How do I pass the parameters fd_map and "3" which are passed in spawn to exec ?

Comment: What does it mean to convert code "which looks like...Linux" to the "Linux equivalent"?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "3" does.

If you want to change the file descriptors available to the child process, you do not do this in the call to `exec` or `fork`, but you do it between by calling `close`, `dup2`, etc.  The function `posix_spawn` basically does this for you, and on Linux/glibc, it is implemented using `fork` and `exec` (so you can read the source code...)

```
pid = fork();
if (!pid) {
    // close, dup2 go here
    exec(...);
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 indicates the number of file descriptors you are passing into the fd_map and in the spawnp() call it allows you to conveniently select only those file descriptors you want to pass along to the child process.

So after your call to fork() you will have all of the file descriptors in the child process so you can close out those file descriptors you aren't interested in and then, assuming that the file descriptors are not marked as CLOEXEC (close on exec) they will also carry through to the exec()'ed code.

Note that the fork() will fail however if your application is multi-threaded since, until recent versions, QNX doesn't support forking threaded processes.